# Magento1: Finding all child (simple) products that are not visible individually without parent (configurable) products set/linked

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

How can I find all `all child (simple) products that are not visible individually without parent (configurable) products set/linked`. these products are not logical as they can never be sold.

I am struggling with this query, however it is not for all to use (attribute id may be different) and I am uncertain if the result is the true answer to my question

```
Select e.entity_id,e.type_id,e.sku,e.created_at,visib.value FROM catalog_product_entity as e LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS visib ON (visib.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND (visib.attribute_id = '95') AND (visib.store_id = 0) WHERE (IF(visib.value_id > 0, 1, 0)) AND e.entity_id  not in (SELECT product_id FROM `catalog_product_super_link`) and type_id='simple' and visib.value = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing you should have in mind is that the visibility attribute has values at **store view** level, so you will have to perform the query for each of your stores.

Here is a query using subselects in order find the simple products which are not associated to any parent product and have visibility *'Not Visible Individually'* in the default store (just replace store_id upon convenience with the ID of your store):

`select * from catalog_product_entity where entity_id in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity_int where attribute_id in (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code='visibility' and entity_type_id=4) and value = 1 and store_id=0) and entity_id not in (select product_id from catalog_product_super_link) and type_id='simple'`

Seeked value = 1 because that's the value of the 'Not visible individually' visibility option (Reference `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE = 1`)

The query works for any database (even m2 :)).

Comment: Cool. And it works. However it selects `all children without a parent`, when it should return  `all children what are not visible individually without a parent`> REALLE APPRECIATE your answer

Comment: i did some tests and it returns all simple products without a parent and that are set as not visible individually. i am not sure if you are validating my answer or say it's missing something

Comment: well, if it does the job, please consider marking this as solution, if not, maybe i can help you tweak it until it does the job. (btw, it does the job) :D :D

Comment: Value = 0 should be the filter I guess

Comment: you can double check this by inspecting the visibility select options in the admin. the option value is '1' for 'Not visible individually' . you can check in the code as well as you have the constant in the model `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE = 1`